# Internal Server Error (500) estimate-shipping-methods

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, shipping-methods, http-error-500

Im using Magento 2 with *Vagrant* and I made a custom theme. Everything works fine except When I add a product to cart and go to Shipping (1st step in checkout) the page loads but when Shipping method tries to load I get error:

> POST http://shop.local/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/ea67f279a751134f7cc2082409178ac7/estimate-shipping-methods 500 (Internal Server Error)

And in response I get:

```
"message": "Each getter must have description with @return annotation. See Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressInterface::getStreet()",
"trace": "
    #0 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(161): Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\TypeProcessor->getGetterReturnType(Object(Zend\\Code\\Reflection\\MethodReflection))\n
    #1 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(322): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('Magento\\\\Quote\\\\A...', Array)\n
    #2 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(119): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue(Array, 'Magento\\\\Quote\\\\A...')\n
    #3 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(101): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Magento\\\\Quote\\\\A...', 'estimateByExten...', Array)\n
    #4 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(299): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n
    #5 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n
    #6 /var/www/shop/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n
    #7 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n
    #8 /var/www/shop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n
    #9 /var/www/shop/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n
    #10 {main}"
```

**NOTE**: Sometimes it is `AddressInterface::getRegionId()`

I went to check the annotations and they are there. I tried to google this problem and found out that [Zend Opcache](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2555) can cause this problem but I already had it disabled. I have PHP version 7.0.6

I also tried to remove Shipping methods same thing (using only Free shipping, rest are disabled).

What else could it be? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made it work not sure how that worked but ok.

So i tried every little thing i could think of so i went to `conf.d/` folder inside my php `etc/php/7.0/cli` and there i saw file `10-opcache.ini` and inside there was a line

```
zend_extention=opcache.so
```

So i have commented it with `;` in front, Restarted my computer and it worked for some reason. Which is confusing as php info was showing that opcache is disabled (maybe it was loading something more from this?)

To add i am using PHP 7.0.6 with Vagrant so this might be different to others.

Comment: We have set the > opcache.enable=0 in etc/php.d/opcache.ini ... Is this correct file to change? If not then can you please suggest us how we can disable in correct way? Thanks!

Comment: try to disable the zend_extension of opcache where it is loaded (comment it). check php_info for the path ( i think it should be there)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. We can see the opcache disabled in php info file. https://www.screencast.com/t/dvYLC7zq9tt

Comment: can you help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to find something like zend_extension = "/../../opcache.so" in php.ini, try to find where extension is loaded and uncomment that. This was my problem also,it was disabled but extension was still being loaded.